# how to get exact initial coordinates of bitmap image in imageview without using onTouch?

Tags: android

I have tried various methods but I want to get bitmap's coordinates when the activity loads so that I can use it to set polygon view.

I have tried using the imageview width and height but the polygon views occupy all of the screen I want the polygon view to be restricted to bit map for that I need the bitmap coordinates.

I want the `(x,y)` coordinates which are written in blue as depicted below.any help would be appreciated.[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1Dub.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular about [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on this site. Please note that this site isn't a replacement for other great online resources like tutorials or books when learning something. Please do some research first, make an attempt to solve this problem yourself (= do coding), and if you get stuck then show us that you have tried. With that you have a good basis to ask a question here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you Q correctly then you need a mathematical sol here to get x,y positions. 1st use bitmap to be set as ImageView.ScaleType= CENTER_INSIDE.
So, your image position is fixed & will touch either X or Y axis.

Calculate ratios:
Br(BitmapRatio) = Bw (bitmapWidth) / Bh (bitmapHeight)

Ir(ImageViewRatio) = Iw / Ih

Now, use below formula:

```
if(Ir > Br) {
  y = 0;
  x = Br*Ih/2;
} else {
  x = 0;
  y = (Iw/Br)/2;
}
```